# How to wait a Thread until a Object is created?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, null

In my android app I need to send Data between two apps. When the GameClient get initialized, it will start three Threads.
The first one will create a Socket and the ReceivingThread. I need to do it in a Thread, because Android won't let me do network connection on MainThread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (mSocket == null) {
                setSocket(new Socket(mAddress, mPort));
                Log.d(TAG, "Client-Socket set.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Socket already set. Skip.");
            }
            mRecCardThread = new ReceivingCardThread();
            mRecCardThread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
mSendCardThread = new SendingCardThread();
mSendCardThread.start();
```

After that I create the third Thread for Sending data.

The problem occurs when I connect to another phone and immediately want to send some Data.

```
mConnection.connectToServer(d.getHost(), d.getPort());
mConnection.sendCard(new int[]{0, 0, 0});
```

My Sending Thread tries to Send data, but will often be called earlier than the `setSocket` method.

```
private synchronized void setSocket(Socket socket) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setSocket called");
    if (mSocket != null) {
        if (mSocket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    mSocket = socket;
    if (mClient != null)
        mClient.mSendCardThread.notifyAll();
    Log.d(TAG, "Notify all, that Socket is set");
}

private class SendingCardThread extends Thread {
    BlockingQueue<int[]> mCardQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    private ObjectOutputStream mOutput;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                int[] nums = mCardQueue.take();
                sendCard(nums);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void sendCard(int[] nums) {
        try {
            if (mOutput == null) {
                while (mSocket == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for Socket to be set.");
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Not waiting anymore.");
                }
                mOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
            }
            mOutput.writeObject(nums);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Client send:" + Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
}
```

So I thought about to let the sending-Thread wait when the Socket is still `null` and when the Socket is created wakeing up the sending-Thread to be sure that the Socket is not null at the beginning.

But this will cause a `IllegalMonitorStateException`: object not locked by thread before notifyAll().
So it seems like it tries to notify but the Sending Thread isn't waiting. But I don't know how to solve this problem. I think also that I don't understand how to use wait() and notify() in praxice.

I hope one of you guys can help me to solve this stupid problem ;D

Comment: Create a Object lock = new Object(); now have your synchronized blocks be based on lock, and invoke wait and notifyAll on lock ( synchronized (lock){  ... lock.wait()} same way have lock.notifyAll inside synchronized (lock){...lock.notifyAll();}

Comment: Why not just create the `Socket` earlier, so the problem cannot arise?

Comment: These are Threads. The Question is how I can be sure that the Socket will created earlier. Also when they appear after each other in code they will start with like 0 ms afterwards so I don't know how to let the others wait until the socket is created.